# Как вызвать activity?

Tags: android, activity, android-intent

Как вызвать activity которая вызвала нашу действующую activity(не указывая явно вызываемый класс во втором параметре интента) через интент или как-нибудь еще, только не кнопкой "BACK"??

Comment: а вы просто сделайте finish() у текущей, она и вызовется

Comment: нужно чтобы она обновилась, так как в нее поступили новые данные из MySql.... а если вызовем finish() то текущая просто завершится и вернет нас к необновленной предыдущей

Comment: Обработайте обновление DB в onRestart (к примеру), той activity к которой возвращаетесь. У вас проблема не раскрывается в вопросе.

Answer (score 2):

Следует вызывать вторую активити методом `StartActivityForResult`(), во второй активти вызывать `setResult()`, и после возвращения в первую реализовывать логику обновления в `onActivityResult()`. Пример взгляни [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/68-urok-29-vyzyvaem-activity-i-poluchaem-rezultat-metod-startactivityforresult)